# Best way to implement switchable pages for a bootstrap SPA

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, bootstrap-4

I am creating a relatively simple web UI for an embedded platform. For layout styling bootstrap 4 seems a nice way to go. The idea is a single page application without using any additional framework. The number of pages is very limited, probably a fixed navbar or tabs with 4 pages. Most of the pages will contain a number of "cards" which show information. Navigation will be controlled from the embedded part via a websocket.

Now more concrete, what is a good way to create "switchable pages" with Bootstrap.

- Hiding showing a div
- Hiding showing a container ( is this possible ? )
- Dynamically create a page from within a Javascript function
- Any other option ?

I do not have much experience with Javascript and web programming, so some pointers or suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to add same class (lets assume it'll be `_view`) and different ids to your "views".
Like this you just do `$('._view').hide(); $('#' +id).show();` every time you need to open some "page".
P. S. Underscore in the class name points to maintainers that this class is not used for styling, but needed for script

Comment: Indeed the most easy way  works without problems. Exactly what I was looking for for a simple SPA.